# modify to email from a list contained in the sheet

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to modify this code to email the people in a list held on a sheet named "Data" under column 1 (A),
Is this possible while still being able to email out the charts?

```
 function 
    emailCharts(sheet,emails,emailSubject){
    var targetspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Active spreadsheet of the key file
    var sheet = targetspreadsheet.getSheetByName('Overview'); // Change the sheet name 
     var emailSubject = 'absence review ';
    var emails = ""; // your email ID
    var charts = sheet.getCharts();


    if(charts.length==0){
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emails,
    subject: "ERROR:"+emailSubject,
    htmlBody: "No charts in the spreadsheet"});    
    return;
    }

    var chartBlobs=new Array(charts.length); 
    var emailBody="Charts<br>";
    var emailImages={};
    for(var i=0;i<charts.length;i++){
    var builder = charts[i].modify();
    builder.setOption('vAxis.format', '#');
    var newchart = builder.build();
    chartBlobs[i]= newchart.getAs('image/png');
    emailBody= emailBody + "<p align='center'><img src='cid:chart"+i+"'> </p>";
    emailImages["chart"+i]= chartBlobs[i];
    }

    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emails,
    subject: emailSubject,
    htmlBody: emailBody,
    inlineImages:emailImages});
    }
```

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

```
var email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data").getRange(1,1).getValue();
```

Comment: Hi this failed to send the email no recipient (line 30, file "emailer")

Comment: You have to paste the code here with line numbers then.

Comment: This code will fail to send unless you pass in an email address as the second argument when calling the function. Your question about how to send to all addresses in a list appears unrelated to this particular error. Do you want to send one email per recipient or have them all as recipients of the same email message?